# How to add context menu for elements in JavaFX webview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webview, javafx

I want to give a context menu on HTML elements in my web view. I have written a piece of code to add the context menu, but it displays wherever I right click on the webview.

```
webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem("Verify"));
        webView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouse) {
                if (mouse.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                   menu.show(webView, mouse.getScreenX(), mouse.getScreenY());
                } else {
                    if (menu != null) {
                        menu.hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Is there a way to display the menu only on clicking some HTML element?
My requirement is such that I should display certain set of menus if I right click on a text field, some other set of menus if I right click on a button, some other set of menus if I right click on a radio button and so on.

Comment: Have a look at the [WebEngine JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) in special the getDocument() method.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can do a check if the element is HTML element using Document object.

Comment: Is the website one of your sites, or is it a only any website on the www? If it is any website, it will be quite painful to get the right element. If it is your site, there is a chance that you can translate it to mouse coordinates.

Comment: It will be any site, not my HTML